How would I equate a character to my type parameter in Haskell?
MRE:
data MRE a = Blah | Eh a | Umm (MRE a) (MRE a) deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

-- function:
foo :: Eq a => Char -> MRE a -> Bool
-- pattern match on Blah here --
foo x (Eh e)
    | x == e = True
    | otherwise = False

Error:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘a’
‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by

Is there a way to fix this short of making MRE a an explicit instance of Eq?

The type signature you have for foo says it should work for any type a that is an instance of Eq. But that's not true. It could only work if a is the type Char. The solution would be to change the type signature to reflect this fact.

foo will be used in an "internal" module and it is basically guaranteed that e will be a Char.

If I change the type signature, I'll have a hard time writing a pattern match for Umm.

Why would you have a harder time writing a pattern match for Umm if you replaced a with Char (and removed the constraint)?

oh, I think I misunderstood you. The assignment explicitly states that this is how the data declaration has to be. Its a little strange but there's not I can do about it :(... although the deriving clause is something that needs to be replaced as a part of the assignment.

@kesarling David wasn't suggesting you change the data declaration. They were suggesting the type signature of foo, so that it now reads foo :: Char -> MRE Char -> Bool. If you know that foo will only ever be used on an MRE Char then that's what the signature for foo should say; claiming that it will work for any MRE a but actually writing code that only works for MRE Char is inconsistent. If you can't guarantee that it's always MRE Char, then you can't compare the e from Eh e with a Char.

Now see, that won't work either. Because I also have to pattern match on the Umm clause.

Why would that prevent you from being able to pattern match on Umm?

@kesarling The Umm case also contains two MRE a values, for the same type a that would be present in the Eh constructor. So if you know the Eh would contain a Char, then the two values in the Umm would also have to be MRE Char values. So you can pattern match on them just fine, and even call foo recursively as it would require MRE Char values. If you want to be able to have a data type MRE that could contain an Eh containing a Char or contain an Umm containing MRE values for some other type, then your MRE data declaration as-is cannot do that.

@kesarling The other way to go instead of specialising the MRE a to MRE Char would be to generalise the Char parameter to a. So you'd end up with foo :: Eq a => a -> MRE a -> Bool. Then you could call it with any type that has an Eq instance, which includes Char. But you wouldn't be able to do anything else specific to Char inside foo, and when you call foo using Char it would still be enforced that second paramter is an MRE Char, whose Umm constructor must contain MRE Chars in turn. You'd just also be able to call it, separately, on an Int and MRE Int, etc.

You are using x == e, but x is a Char, and e is of type a. If you thus add an Eq a [Hackage] type constraint you can use (==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool function [Hackage], but only if the two operands are a.
This thus works if a is a Char:
foo :: Char -> MRE Char -> Bool
foo x (Eh e) = x == e
or you need to inject a function to compare the a with a Char, so:
foo :: (a -> Char -> Bool) -> a -> MRE Char -> Bool
foo f x (Eh e) = f x e
It might also be possible, As @chi says in their comment, that your first parameter does not have to be a Char, but can be generalized to a, so then we can work with:
foo :: Eq a => a -> MRE a -> Bool
foo x (Eh e) = x == e

foo :: Eq a => a -> MRE a -> Bool is also a possibility.

yes, this is what was actually expected in the first place. I had misunderstood the assignment. :(
